# Windows Phone 8 applications link in Microsoft Dev Center are invalid - show error

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have released an App for Windows Phone 8 and it shows up if I search in store.
I wanted to get links to it in dev center, and when I click on them the page shows up that says that "We're sorry, the page you requested could not be found".

What can I do to fix that? I need the links for marketing.

Here are the links in question:

http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=a52a4024-7508-46fe-a723-4f5c20739d3f
https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9nblggh5z9cd

Answer (score 1):

Hi Dvole : Congratulation Your App is Approved from Microsoft. But It take 4 to 6 hour time to come in Windows App store. So be pationate your App will be Display soon.. on this link..